# How to execute Javascript inside a usercontrol inside an updatepanel

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Webforms project, where a UserControl is shown/hidden depending on the value of a DropDownList.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlUpdate" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Type 1" Value="1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Type 2" Value="2" />
      </asp:DropDownList>

      <myControl:myCustomControl Visible="false" />
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

in the code behind, `myCustomControl` is set to `Visible=true` or `Visible=false` depending on the type and nothing more

This all works, but my `myCustomControl` has a few JavaScript functions in it, and they aren't executed. I suppose this is because of the `UpdatePanel` dynamically refreshing and loading the `myCustomControl`.

It contains code like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server" onchange="myJavascriptFunction()">
   <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Without the UpdatePanel:**: everything works as expected and the `myJavaScriptFunction()` gets executed just fine.

**With the UpdatePanel:**: the `myJavascriptFunction()` is not executed. The generic error message `myJavaScriptFunction is not a function` is printed to the console.

So, how can I make this work? Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: where does myJavascriptFunction is defined?

Comment: it's inside myCustomControl. I suspect the browser isn't parsing the javascript since it's loaded asynchronously because of the updatepanel.

Comment: can you check if js function is rendered at the time of page load? try once with Visible="true"